# Dynamically writing the objective function and constraints for scipy.optimize.minimize from matrices

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, constraints, mathematical-optimization

In my code, I am trying to write a while loop that updates the values of x using scipy.optimize.minimize using the SQSLP option as I have inequality and equality constraints. In addition to updating x, this results in updating the values within the objective function and constraints.

Below is the section that calls all the functions that update the constraints and objective function at a given x

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

num_vars = 2
num_eq_cons = 1
num_ineq_cons = 1


# return the desired initial value for x
def x_init():
    x = np.zeros([num_vars,1], dtype = float)
    x[0] = 2
    x[1] = 1
    return x

# Objective
# needs the current value of x (x_k)
def eval_objective(x):
    f = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2
    return float(f)

# Inequality Constraints
# need the current value of x (x_k)
def eval_ineq_cons(x):
    g = np.zeros([num_ineq_cons,1], dtype = float)
    g[0] = x[0]**2 - x[1]
    return g

# Equality Constraints
# need the current value of x (x_k)
def eval_eq_cons(x):
    h = np.zeros([num_eq_cons, 1], dtype = float)
    h[0] = 2 - x[0] - x[1]**2
    return h

# Taylor series Approximations
# needs the current value of x
# For objective
def eval_part_obj(x):
    dfdx = np.zeros([num_vars,1], dtype = float)
    dfdx[0] = 2*x[0]
    dfdx[1] = 2*x[1]
    return dfdx

# For inequalities
def eval_part_ineq_cons(x):
    dgdx = np.zeros([num_ineq_cons, num_vars], dtype = float)
    dgdx[0,0] = 2*x[0]
    dgdx[0,1] = -1.0
    return dgdx

# For equalities
def eval_part_eq_cons(x):
    dhdx = np.zeros([num_eq_cons, num_vars], dtype = float)
    dhdx[0,0] = -1
    dhdx[0,1] = -2*x[1]
    return dhdx

x_k = x_init() # Initialization point
f_k = eval_objective(x_k)
dfdx = eval_part_obj(x_k)
g_k = eval_ineq_cons(x_k)
dgdx = eval_part_ineq_cons(x_k)
h_k = eval_eq_cons(x_k)
dhdx = eval_part_eq_cons(x_k)
```

The code below is the code where I get my errors:

```
fun = lambda x_k1: f_k + dfdx[0]*(x_k1[0] - x_k[0]) + dfdx[1]*(x_k1[1] - x_k[1])

cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x_k1: g_k + np.dot(dgdx, (x_k1 - x_k)).squeeze(),
         'jac': dgdx},
        {'type': 'eq',
         'fun': lambda x_k1: h_k + np.dot(dhdx, (x_k1 - x_k)).squeeze(),
         'jac': dhdx})

bnds = [(.5, 2.5), (0,3)]

res = minimize( fun, x_k, method = 'SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints = cons)
print(res)
```

The error that I obtain is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SLPmain.py", line 104, in <module>
    res = minimize( fun, x_k, method = 'SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints = cons)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 358, in minimize
    constraints, **options)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 376, in _minimize_slsqp
    for con in cons['eq']])
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to write the constraints and objective function in a better way!

Comment: Interesting problem. If I read correctly, you are minimizing a quadratic under quadratic inequality constraints and linear equality constraints. If this is the case, wouldn't you be able to use dual variables to separate the constrained variables into two different ones, minimize them and then maximize the dual objective?

Comment: Don't know if it solves the problem. But `jac` has to be a callable, not a numpy array. And you're missing the definitions of `bnds` in your code here.

Comment: The objective function and the constraints are supposed to be all linear in respect to x_k1. f_k, dfdx, g_k, dgdx, h_k, dhdx and x_k are constants at a given x_k. Also, yes I forgot to include the bnds in this statement. If I would omit the Jac, I get this:  ValueError: output operand requires a reduction, but reduction is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious problems:

1, the Jacobians for both the inequality and equality constrains are both `array` not callables (functions), as they are defined as :

```
dgdx = eval_part_ineq_cons(x_k)
dhdx = eval_part_eq_cons(x_k)
```

They are function returns (therefore `array`s) not functions.

2, The constrain function returns are not scalars, they are `array`s. e.g.:

```
g_k + np.dot(dgdx, (x_k1 - x_k)).squeeze()
```

The way to correct this would depended on your real work problems, there are alternatives such as:

```
(g_k + np.dot(dgdx, (x_k1 - x_k)).squeeze()).sum()
```

or

```
((g_k + np.dot(dgdx, (x_k1 - x_k)).squeeze())**2).sum() #sum of squares.
```

Same problem for inequality constrain. 
I suspect this is because `fun` is passed to `fmin_slsqp` as `eqcons` not `f_eqcons`. If you want the all elements in the equality constrain function returns ==0, probably you should use `fmin_slsqp` directly and pass the constrain functions `f_eqcons`.

Therefore, it can be as followes:

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x_k1: (g_k + np.dot(dgdx, (x_k1 - x_k)).squeeze()).sum(),
         'jac':  eval_part_ineq_cons},
        {'type': 'eq',
         'fun': lambda x_k1: (h_k + np.dot(dhdx, (x_k1 - x_k)).squeeze()).sum(),
         'jac': eval_part_eq_cons})
```

And the result is:

```
In [31]:

res
Out[31]:
  status: 9
 success: False
    njev: 101
    nfev: 1385
     fun: array([ 2.69798824])
       x: array([ 1.89963627,  0.04972158])
 message: 'Iteration limit exceeded'
     jac: array([ 4.,  2.,  0.])
     nit: 101
```

Actually, notice that the optimization failed. I suspect it is not going to guarantee to work when you have the Jacobian constrains. Removing the Jac's and it will work (although may not be the way that you want it).

```
In [29]:

res
Out[29]:
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 11
    nfev: 122
     fun: array([ 1.33333333])
       x: array([ 0.5       ,  2.16666667])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     jac: array([ 4.,  2.,  0.])
     nit: 15
```

Comment: This does fix the problem of why it doesn't work but the result of the optimization is not what it should be. The optimal should be x = (11/9, 8/9) but that's way off.

Comment: That is not entirely surprising, as the optimization failed when `jac` is specified. But you see the two critical points right? My suspicion is that it may have to to with the equality constrain. Do you want ALL the cells in equality constrain function return to be 0?

Comment: Yes, I do see the 2 critical points and yes I do want all the equality constraints to return to zero.

Comment: You can keep the jac and increase the max number of iteration. It looks like it is headed in the right direction.